# OpenJpa2.0 How to map Oracle sys.XMLTYPE column to String

Tags: oracle11g, openjpa, websphere-7, ora-01461

I changed Change in persistence.xml 
I also changed column definition (columnDefinition="XDB.XMLType") for xml fields

I checked OpenJpa(http://openjpa.208410.n2.nabble.com/Oracle-XMLType-fetch-problems-td6208344.html) site and IBM (http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7J6S_7.5.0/com.ibm.wsadapters.jca.jdbc.doc/env/doc/rjdb_problemsolutions.html)

My env is OpenJpa 2.0 and WAS 7

its throwing exception
 org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small 
     ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 169

Please suggest without changing OpenJpa2.0 as its part of IBM WebSphere Application Server V7.0 how can i handle sys.XMLTYPE data, i am migrating my application from db2 to Oracle in same environment.

Comment: How many characters is the XML you are dealing with?

Comment: its a big xml file more than 4000 char

Answer (score 1):

Writing XML data can be tricky some times!  Getting the correct drivers and things defined properly can have its challenges.  I can not say exactly what you need to do given the lack of info on your domain model and such, but let me give some general things to look for.  First, there is an XML test in the OpenJPA test framework if you want to make reference to it.  It can be seen publicly here:

https://apache.googlesource.com/openjpa/+/refs/heads/trunk/openjpa-persistence-jdbc/src/test/java/org/apache/openjpa/jdbc/oracle/

Or, another test using an "XMLValueHandler" (likely this is beyond the scope of what you are looking for):

https://apache.googlesource.com/openjpa/+/refs/heads/trunk/openjpa-persistence-jdbc/src/test/java/org/apache/openjpa/persistence/xmlmapping/query/

Second, (stating the obvious) I assume you have a column in Oracle defined as "XMLTYPE".  Also, I see you are using schema SYS.  I'm sure you are aware but this is a system/admin schema......just for sanity sake you might want to first get things running using a non-system/admin schema just so we don't get hung up with any issues with your OpenJPA client not having the correct permissions.

Next, you need the following definition:

```
@Lob @Basic
@Column(name = "ANXMLCOLUMN", columnDefinition="XMLCOLUMN XMLType")
private String anXMLString;
```

The @Lob I think will be necessary if you are using data greater than 4000 chars (this was mentioned in one of the comments).  To start I'd use a very small set of data (a couple characters), once that works, then experiment with > 4k.

Next, make sure to use the correct JDBC driver.  The last time I experimented with an XMLType I used the Oracle JDBC 11.2.0.2 driver.

Finally, you might need to use the property "openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" with value "oracle(supportsSetClob=true,maxEmbeddedClobSize=-1)".  Again, experiment with this AND look at the OpenJPA documentation on these properties to determine if they are necessary in your scenario.  I think the supportsSetClob=true will only be necessary for older version (pre-2.2.x) of OpenJPA.  You might also need to use property "openjpa.jdbc.SchemaFactory" with value "native".  I would suggest you first try without either or these two properties.  If that doesn't help, then experiment with these two properties.  I know this is vague, but I don't know what your DDL or domain model looks like so I have to keep in vague.

Thanks,

Heath Thomann